# Windows fax console: send NOW a fax that is in the outbox

Tags: windows, fax

I am using Windows Fax Console.

I sent a Fax but it failed, and it went to the Outbox to wait until Windows tries to send it again.

How can I control when is it going to be sent again? Or tell the fax console to send it immediately?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Fax Service Manager", right-click on the fax (local), select Properties, choose the "Outbox" tab, you have retry and "retry-after" options there.
AFAIK, there is no "Send the (*&)!! thing now" button.. but I wish there was!

Comment: How do you get to the Fax Service Manger on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I did following:
in outbox right click on fax to sent
click pause
right click
click resume

it started immediately.  Perhaps it was just the retry time had elapsed but it worked once.

Comment: Retry time elapsed about 10 years ago.

Comment: @AJD: It might be an old thread and the answer might be of no use for the OP anymore, but for people like me, who have searched NOW (yet another year later) for such an issue, it is still a helpful comment.